# What are the outcomes of killing and sparing the Shaelmaar?

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine

The game gives you the option to kill the Shaelmaar.
Normally that kind of option would influence the outcome of the story somehow.
In the Shaelmaar's case, does it influence the story? Do you get any reward whether you kill him or not?

Comment: Probably it does. In the Witcher, almost everything has an effect. Load back from a save and try the other way ... have fun and experiment!

Comment: Bryan, my question is more about how the action will influence the game and less about the reward from killing the beast. I know I mentioned the reward at the end, but just for curiosity. The main question is about how it will change the history.

Comment: I just let him live straight out of principle. What Geralt says is right, it's only there to be slain so that the crowd can be entertained. It isn't a threat to humans.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you **spare** the **Shaelmaar** you will get **one** of **five** virtues.

The virtue that you get is **Compassion**.

There is one side-quest (**'There can be only one' Quest**) in which you must have all the virtues. (I won't spoil anything).

So all-in-all, you sparing the monster won't have any immediate effects or any **large** repercussions, since **Compassion** is one of the virtues you can get in another situation in the DLC.

Just FYI and to feed curiosity the virtues are:

- **Generosity**
- **Valor**
- **Compassion**
- **Honor**
- **Wisdom**

Comment: Thank you! I was sure that "timed dialog" wasn't there by accident!!! Thank god I spared the creature!